# search and replace in entire project on linux/osx

Tags: replace

How would I replace one pattern with another for every file with extension .cc and .h recursively?  Not sure if I need to prevent it from going into .svn directories.

first attempt

```
#!/bin/bash
for file in `find . -name '*.cc' -or -name  '*.h'`; do \
    sed -e s/$1/$2/g -i temp $file
done
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your project is managed under linux platform, You can do sth like that inside the bash:

```
for file in `find . -name '*.cpp' -or -name  '*.h'`; do \
     cat $file | sed s/$1/$2/g > tmp
     mv tmp $file
done
```

Each svn file has '*-base' extension so all of them will be unchanged. This script will only affect to *h and *cc files.

Comment: doesn't work.  What am I doing wrong?

 #!/bin/bash
 for file find . -name '*.cc' -or -name  '*.h'; do \
    sed -i s/$1/$2/g $file
 done

Comment: You forgot about semicolon after $file and before 'done' command.
Semicolon is needed because your command is in one line.

This is proper version: 
#!/bin/bash for file find . -name '*.cc' -or -name '*.h'; do \ sed -i s/$1/$2/g $file; done

Answer (score 0):

You can search and replace using regular expressions through certain files in Eclipse project explorer, for example. I'm sure there are lots of tools that can do this, but Elipse comes to mind first.

To do this you need to invoke the "Search" dialog, place your pattern in the search field, specify extensions with a wildcard and press "Replace",